# JSON(incorrect) to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a (incorrect)JSON file that I want to convert to a CSV tabel.
Bellow I show two rows (2 of the 2500) of the JSON file:

```
{
   "usage":{
      "text_characters":7653,
      "features":2,
      "text_units":1
   },
   "emotion":{
      "document":{
         "emotion":{
            "anger":0.085554,
            "joy":0.526103,
            "sadness":0.533085,
            "fear":0.148549,
            "disgust":0.078346
         }
      }
   },
   "language":"en",
   "sentiment":{
      "document":{
         "score":-0.323271,
         "label":"negative"
      }
   },
   "retrieved_url":"http://blogs.plos.org/speakingofmedicine/2017/01/20/the-why-vaccines-dont-cause-autism-papers/"
}{
   "usage":{
      "text_characters":5528,
      "features":2,
      "text_units":1
   },
   "emotion":{
      "document":{
         "emotion":{
            "anger":0.160801,
            "joy":0.443317,
            "sadness":0.596578,
            "fear":0.555745,
            "disgust":0.127581
         }
      }
   },
   "language":"en",
   "sentiment":{
      "document":{
         "score":-0.558026,
         "label":"negative"
      }
   },
   "retrieved_url":"http://www.cnn.com/2011/HEALTH/01/05/autism.vaccines/index.html"
}
```

However I want to convert this to a CSV table like this with python:

```
usage__text_characters  usage__features usage__text_units   emotion__document__emotion__anger   emotion__document__emotion__joy emotion__document__emotion__sadness emotion__document__emotion__fear    emotion__document__emotion__disgust language    sentiment__document__score  sentiment__document__label  retrieved_url
7653    2   1   0.085554    0.526103    0.533085    0.148549    0.078346    en  -0.323271   negative    http://blogs.plos.org/speakingofmedicine/2017/01/20/the-why-vaccines-dont-cause-autism-papers/
5528    2   1   0.160801    0.443317    0.596578    0.555745    0.127581    en  -0.558026   negative    http://www.cnn.com/2011/HEALTH/01/05/autism.vaccines/index.html
```

I have tried several thinks already without success(I merged the things that I already have tried):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
    dd = json.load(data_file)
    print dd
df = pd.read_json('data.json').unstack().dropna()
data = pd.read_json('data.json', lines=True)
with open('data.json', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
data = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(), data)
data_json_str = "[" + ','.join(data) + "]"
data_df = pd.read_json(data_json_str)
```

The answer of @JeffMercado solved the question

Comment: Consider using tools that are designed to work with json data such as [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). It could turn that into csv fairly trivially. And it can even handle the stream of inputs no problem.

Comment: This is what the jq version could look like: `jq -r '([leaf_paths|join("__")], ((.,inputs)|[getpath(leaf_paths)]))|@csv' data.json`

Comment: @JeffMercado this is the first time that I am working with jq. I have executed your code inside the terminal (Ubuntu). The output that I see inside the terminal looks fine. However, where is the CSV file saved?

Comment: Well by default it would output to stdout, but you could redirect that to a file.

Comment: This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Far from the smoothest of solutions but you could read the data in as dictionaries that you update and later insert to a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    # correct the wrong encoded json string
    data = "[" + ','.join(['{"usage'+e for e in data.split('{"usage') if e]) + "]"
    data = json.loads(data)

rows_list = []
cols = []

for ind,row in enumerate(data):

    # Only to get column names
    if ind == 0:
        cols.append(["usage__{}".format(i) for i in row["usage"].keys()])
        cols.append(["emotion__document__emotion__{}".format(i) for i in row["emotion"]["document"]["emotion"].keys()])
        cols.append(["sentiment__document__{}".format(i) for i in row["sentiment"]["document"].keys()])
        cols.append(["retrieved_url"])

    d = OrderedDict()

    d.update(row["usage"])
    d.update(row["emotion"]["document"]["emotion"])
    d.update(row["sentiment"]["document"])
    d.update({"retrieved_url":row["retrieved_url"]})

    rows_list.append(d)


df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
df.columns = [i for subitem in cols for i in subitem]

#output without index
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">  <thead>    <tr style="text-align: right;">      <th></th>      <th>usage__text_characters</th>      <th>usage__features</th>      <th>usage__text_units</th>      <th>emotion__document__emotion__anger</th>      <th>emotion__document__emotion__joy</th>      <th>emotion__document__emotion__sadness</th>      <th>emotion__document__emotion__fear</th>      <th>emotion__document__emotion__disgust</th>      <th>sentiment__document__score</th>      <th>sentiment__document__label</th>      <th>retrieved_url</th>    </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>    <tr>      <th>0</th>      <td>7653</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>0.085554</td>      <td>0.526103</td>      <td>0.533085</td>      <td>0.148549</td>      <td>0.078346</td>      <td>-0.323271</td>      <td>negative</td>      <td>http://blogs.plos.org/speakingofmedicine/2017/...</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>1</th>      <td>5528</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>0.160801</td>      <td>0.443317</td>      <td>0.596578</td>      <td>0.555745</td>      <td>0.127581</td>      <td>-0.558026</td>      <td>negative</td>      <td>http://www.cnn.com/2011/HEALTH/01/05/autism.va...</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>2</th>      <td>11640</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>0.062221</td>      <td>0.144592</td>      <td>0.200812</td>      <td>0.151575</td>      <td>0.075855</td>      <td>-0.628669</td>      <td>negative</td>      <td>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMR_vaccine</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>3</th>      <td>3079</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>0.134388</td>      <td>0.104364</td>      <td>0.254788</td>      <td>0.265767</td>      <td>0.082326</td>      <td>-0.413833</td>      <td>negative</td>      <td>https://immunize.ca/resources/89</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>4</th>      <td>3074</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>0.125521</td>      <td>0.521253</td>      <td>0.242785</td>      <td>0.559390</td>      <td>0.062896</td>      <td>-0.234100</td>      <td>negative</td>      <td>https://www.autismspeaks.org/what-autism/learn...</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>5</th>      <td>4295</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>1</td>      <td>0.093873</td>      <td>0.483575</td>      <td>0.509759</td>      <td>0.487799</td>      <td>0.046805</td>      <td>-0.328508</td>      <td>negative</td>      <td>https://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/autism/topics.html</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>6</th>      <td>17654</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>2</td>      <td>0.069062</td>      <td>0.512447</td>      <td>0.544514</td>      <td>0.510827</td>      <td>0.078509</td>      <td>-0.517533</td>      <td>negative</td>      <td>https://www.healthychildren.org/English/safety...</td>    </tr>  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: How would you suggest me to import the .json file?

Comment: @TanjaMeeren I thought it wasn't a json file but a file with rows? Assumes **rows**=[row1,row2, ... , rown]

Comment: No the file is a .JSON file

Comment: Read above: " Bellow I show two rows (2 of the 2500) of the JSON file:"

Comment: @TanjaMeeren We are misunderstanding each other. I have updated the answer however with what I Think is what you are asking for.

Comment: I receive a error     cols.append(["usage__{}".format(i) for i in row["usage"].keys()])

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @TanjaMeeren Corrected the answer to load that json (it looks really strange)

Comment: It works, except that the headers are not correct if I change the last row to df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list)
df.columns = [i for subitem in cols for i in subitem]
df.to_csv("output.csv", sep=',')

Comment: @TanjaMeeren the headers come from the dataframe (I used index=False) in df.to_csv to remove index column. What is not correct?

Comment: The headers are not in line with actual values. For example at retrieved_url
I see the value "1" what actual should show the url. I tried it with #df.to_csv('your.csv', sep=',', index=False) and
df.to_csv('your.csv', index=False). However that is not such a big problem, I can correct that after in LibreOffice

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a bit late, but my coworker was determined to make a solution using a recursive function so I'll share it.

```
import json, pandas
with open('emotions.json') as emotions:
    emotions = json.load(emotions)

def flattener(my_dict, return_dict={}, mykey=''):
    for key,item in my_dict.items():
        if isinstance(my_dict[key],dict):
            return_dict = flattener(item,return_dict,mykey+'__'+str(key))
        else:
            return_dict[mykey+'__'+str(key)] = item
    return return_dict


dictionary = {}
for key in flattener(emotions[0]).keys():
    # get flattened keys and make a new dictionary of lists with them
    dictionary[key[2:]] = []

for emotion in emotions:
    # get more flattened dictionaries and store them in our
    # dictionary of lists
    for key, value in flattener(emotion).items():
        dictionary[key[2:]].append(value)
# pandas make writing to csv easy
df = pandas.DataFrame(dictionary)

df.to_csv('csv_name.csv')
```